# Spring proxy to choose implementation based on annotation and runtime value

Tags: java, spring, proxy, scope

I would like to inject a proxy implementation of an interface to a component and then let spring choose the right implementation based on a runtime property (and the value of an annotation at the implementation class). So my component does not have to care about choosing the right one.

It is kind of like a scope. But i think scopes are only for handling different instances of the same implementation class. Am i wrong with this?

I would like this to run for arbitrary interfaces without creating a service locator or some other construct for every new service.

Here is an example.

Suppose I have an interface defining a service

```
package test;

public interface IService {
  void doSomething();
}
```

and two implementations:

```
package test;

import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@MyAnnotation("service1")
public class Service1 implements IService {

  @Override
  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("this");
  }
}
```

...

```
package test;

import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@MyAnnotation("service2")
public class Service2 implements IService {

  @Override
  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("that");
  }
}
```

Now I would like to inject an IService to another component and let spring choose the correct implementation based on some queryable run time property and the value of MyAnnotation.

Is there a way to do this in a general way in spring?

EDIT:

I have a Context that holds some value. It is a thread local in this case.

```
package test;
public class MyValueHolder {

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> value = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void set(String newValue) {
        value.set(newValue);
    }

    public static String get() {
        return value.get();
    }

    public static void reset() {
        value.remove();
    }
}
```

And I have an component which uses `IService`

```
package test;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
public class MyComponent {

    @Inject
    private IService service;

    public void myImportantWorkflow(){

        MyValueHolder.set("service1");
        service.doSomething();

        MyValueHolder.set("service2");
        service.doSomething();
    }
}
```

The injected service should only be a proxy. Depending on the value set in `MyValueHolder` the call to `doSomething` should delegate to service1 or service2. So in this example  it should delegate to doSomething on service1 in the first call and to service2 in the second call.

I could write such a delegator implementing the `IService` interface and use it for this one service. But then i have to repeat this for every other service . I hoped spring could do something like this with proxies almost by itself. Of course i have to provide some method to look beans up based on the value hold in the thread local and register it to spring. But i have no idea if that is even possible without modifying the spring framework. And if it is possible how to accomplish this.

Comment: It all depends on what you mean by 'let spring choose the correct implementation based on some queryable run time property and the value of MyAnnotation'. You should probably write a unit test to flesh out the behavior you expect.

Comment: 'Let spring chhose the right implementation' means that spring does some kind of lookup with the interface type and the annotation value to get the correct implementation the injected proxy then calls this looked up implementation.

Comment: Spring already inspects the type and uses the [@Qualifier](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) annotation to select which bean to inject.

Comment: Yes, but `@Qualifier` injects implementation by name. But the point is that i have two implementations and only one should be used for a  call. Which one should be determined by inspecting a run time value (in fact a threadlocal value). So i call the `doSomeThing()` Method on the `IService`, now the value of a thread local should be inspected. If it contains "service1" the call is delegated to `Service1` and if it contains "service2" it is delegated to `Service2`. This lookup should happen transparently to the class that uses the `IService`

Comment: @Finn Can you elaborate a little more on how the selection would occur? A little more info would hhelp

Comment: Thanks for the update! AFAIK there is nothing out of the box that supports what you are looking for

Comment: This could be implemented easily but you will have to do all the work. You will have to implement the IService proxy which will need to have a registry of all IService implementations and a method to resolve which one to use. In any case, I think this is in general a bad idea.

Comment: @RicardoVeguilla: It could be implemented easily for one interface. And i know how to do that. But to build this for all interfaces whose implementations are annotated with `@MyAnnotation` is not so easy. But why do you think it is a bad idea? I think this is conceptionally not so much different from proxy based scope implementations like request or session scope. So how would you decide which implementation to use at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `ProxyFactoryBean` to create the proxies and a `TargetSource` to do the lookup.

For example (not tested)

```
public class AnnotatedBeanTargetSource implements TargetSource, BeanFactoryAware {

    private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory;
    private Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType;
    private Class<?> implementedIterface;
    private Map<String, Object> beans;

    @Override
    public Class<?> getTargetClass() {
        return this.implementedIterface;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStatic() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getTarget() throws Exception {
        if (this.beans == null) {
            this.beans = lookupTargets();
        }

        return this.beans.get(MyValueHolder.get());
    }

    protected Map<String, Object> lookupTargets() { 
        Map<String, Object> resolvedBeans = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        String[] candidates = beanFactory.getBeanNamesForAnnotation(annotationType);
        for (String beanName : candidates) {
            Class<?> type = beanFactory.getType(beanName);

            if (this.implementedIterface.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
                Annotation ann = AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(type, annotationType);
                resolvedBeans.put((String) AnnotationUtils.getValue(ann), beanFactory.getBean(beanName));
            }
        }

        return resolvedBeans;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseTarget(Object target) throws Exception {
        // nothing to do
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = (ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) beanFactory;

    }

    public Class<? extends Annotation> getAnnotationType() {
        return annotationType;
    }

    public void setAnnotationType(Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType) {
        this.annotationType = annotationType;
    }

    public Class<?> getImplementedIterface() {
        return implementedIterface;
    }

    public void setImplementedIterface(Class<?> implementedIterface) {
        this.implementedIterface = implementedIterface;
    }
}
```

Comment: This pointed me to the right direction. I used a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` to create proxy bean definitions and mark the real implementations as not being candidates for autowiring. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
@Named
public class MyComponent {

    // introduce a marker interface for Injecting proxies
    @InjectDynamic
    IService service
    ...

    public void useIService() {
       service.doSomething();
       ...
       service.doSomethingElse();
       ...
       service.doFinally();
    }
}
```

Define a  [BeanPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) that scans for bean with fields annotated with `@InjectDynamic`, then creates and inject a Proxy implementing the type required by the field.

The Proxy implementation will look in the applicationContext for beans implementing `Supplier<T>` (Java 8 or guava versions) where `<T>` is the type of the field annotated with `@InjectDynamic`.

Then you can define

```
@Name
public IServiceSupplier implements Supplier<IService> {
     @Override
     public IService get() {
            // here you implement the look-up logic for IService
     }
}
```

In this way the look-up of active the current implementation is decoupled from the Proxy and can be change by target type.

Comment: Just to be clear, I think this is a bad idea in general **unless you can guarantee that the Proxy will not change the implementation of IService that MyComponent during a method invocation of a MyComponent method**. Which means that you will have to Proxy MyComponent too.